# Common ground with two bridge rectifiers

Tags: ground, bridge-rectifier, nixie

I have a transformer with multiple taps on the secondary coil delivering many different voltages and I want to know if I blow something up when I convert the AC of the transformer to DC with bridge rectifiers and then connect the ground.

Comment: Go edit your question, press Ctrl+M, and draw a schematic of what you propose doing. The textual description is way to hand wavey.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the secondaries are made with isolated windings, if you try and add 2 or more bridge rectifiers you will find that commoning up the "ground" output side of the bridges will short out the windings. There are many variations of secondaries with taps but I'm yet to see one that doesn't ALWAYS short out the winding in one direction of current flow.

See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153399/using-all-the-taps-of-the-transformer-at-the-same-time/153403#153403) Dave Tweed answer

Also see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61270/common-dc-ground-with-two-bridge-rectifiers) answer